# Is there a way to replace characters in a string from index 0 to index -4 (i.e. all but last 4 characters) with a '#'

Tags: python-3.x

For example, If my string was 'HelloWorld'

I want the output to be ######orld

My Code:

```
myString = 'ThisIsAString'
hashedString = string.replace(string[:-4], '#')
print(hashedString)

Output >> #ring
```

I expected the output to have just one # symbol since it is replacing argument 1 with argument 2.


Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply # by the word length - 4 and then use the string slicing.

```
myString = 'HelloWorld'
print('#' * (len(myString) - 4) + myString[-4:])

myString = 'ThisIsAString'
print('#' * (len(myString) - 4) + myString[-4:])
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.replace(old, new)` replaces all instances of `old` with `new`. So the code you provided is actually replacing the entire beginning of the string with a single pound sign.

You will also notice that input like `abcdabcd` will give the output `##`, since you are replacing all 'abcd' substrings.

Using replace, you could do

```
hashes = '#' * len(string[:-4])
hashedString = string.replace(string[:-4], hashes, 1)
```

Note the string multiplication to get the right number of pound symbols, and the 1 passed to replace, which tells it only to replace the first case it finds.

A better method would be to not use replace at all:

```
hashes = '#' * (len(string) - 4)
leftover = string[-4:]
hashedString = hashes + leftover
```

This time we do the same work with getting the pound sign string, but instead of replacing we just take the last 4 characters and add them after the pound signs.